# How to remove nginx for WAMP installed on Windows OS

Tags: php, nginx, wampserver

I am using WAMP server on my Windows OS system. It was working fine till yesterday's day end. But when I start my computer today, and start WAMP server, while accessing localhost it showing me below text.

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

Dose any one know about this problem? Please suggest solution if any one face this issue in past.

Comment: use `taskkill /f /im nginx.exe` in command prompt with admin privileges and then access `localhost`, if that works then you have to edit nginx.conf so that it must listen to another port or remove nginx completely

Comment: WAMPServer(Apache) is a web server. NGINX is a web server. **Therefore both are trying to use port 80** One web server per PC is the simplest idea, but if you want both then change NGINX so it does not _AutoStart_ in the services snapin. WAMPServer does not set Apache to _AutoStart_ Then start whichever one you want to use, you may need to learn to use `net start nginx` from the command line to start NGINX manually.

Comment: Alternatively - You sound surprised that NGINX is on your system, if you dont want it, uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks all of you to help me. I have removed it from my system and wamp is working now.